# create the RelativeLayout with the same height and width when using the weight property for width

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `RelativeLayout`  with the weight property for width , and using the `130dp` for height , but it seem's like a rectangle and now i want height equal to width (i want to achieve to square style) , like this image :

[image]

this is my xml :

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00c4ff"
            android:onClick="blockClick">

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00c4ff"
            android:onClick="blockClick">

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your own implementation of `RelativeLayout`
Code sample for [aspect ratio ImageView](https://gist.github.com/JakeWharton/2856179)

Code example:

```
public class MyRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout{

[...]

@Override 
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    int newWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
    int newHeight = newWidth;

    setMeasuredDimension(newWidth, newHeight);
  }

[...]

}
```

Comment: and what should i write in the height property for relativelayout in xml ?

Comment: `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` this property is ignored.

Answer (score 3):

Use custom RelativeLayout...

```
public class SquareRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {

    public SquareRelativeLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int width = getMeasuredWidth();
        setMeasuredDimension(width, width);
    }
}
```

Comment: and what should i write in the height property for relativelayout in xml ?

Comment: height property is ignored with this approach so it doesn't matter. A better way is getting width from the widthMeasureSpec as follows.

int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec)

Comment: @majid you should use height as... android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about different screen of device, there is one solution:

1. Get the width of the screen. W
2. divide the W: W/2
3. Set every height of the RelativeLayout with W/2

I have used this solution to set the image View with fix ratio on different screen.

```
    layout.width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    layout.height = (int) (layout.width / (2.0));
    mRelativeView.setLayoutParams(layout);
```